# What's the difference between the two closure

Tags: swift, escaping, closures

I tried comment and uncomment the `activity()` in the following code. I found when I commented the `activity()` the result in playground would just show "play tennis" once. However it would show twice if I uncommented `activity()`. What's the difference between the two statements?

```
class Baby {
    var name = "peter"
    var favoriteActivity: (() -> ())!

    func outsideActivity(activity: @escaping () -> ()) {
        //activity()
        favoriteActivity = activity
    }
}

var cuteBaby = Baby()
cuteBaby.outsideActivity {
    print("play tennis")
}
cuteBaby.favoriteActivity()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what’s going on:

1. Consider this method:

   ```
   func outsideActivity(activity: @escaping () -> ()) {
       //activity()
       favoriteActivity = activity
   }
   ```

   All that does is save the closure in the `favoriteActivity` property

   Thus, when you do:

   ```
   // create `Baby` instance

   var cuteBaby = Baby()

   // this method saves closure in `favoriteActivity`, but doesn’t call it

   cuteBaby.outsideActivity {
       print("play tennis")
   }

   // this now calls the closure

   cuteBaby.favoriteActivity()
   ```

   All the `outsideActivity` method does is save the closure in a property called `favoriteActivity`.

   Thus you see one `print` statement.
2. However, now consider this method:

   ```
   func outsideActivity(activity: @escaping () -> ()) {
       activity()
       favoriteActivity = activity
   }
   ```

   This actually calls the closure before saving it in the property.

   So, when you do:

   ```
   // create `Baby` instance

   var cuteBaby = Baby()

   // this method both calls the closure and then also saves it in `favoriteActivity`

   cuteBaby.outsideActivity {
       print("play tennis")
   }

   // this now calls the saved closure a second time

   cuteBaby.favoriteActivity()
   ```

   In this case, you’ll see your `print` statement being called twice.

That’s why the first rendition calls the closure only once, whereas the second calls the closure twice.

---

Usually when you pass a closure to a method, you either (a) call the closure from within the method (perhaps in some completion handler or the like); or (b) save the closure in some property so you can call it later.

So, this second example is very unusual, where `outsideActivity` both calls the closure itself and saves that closure in some property so you can call it again later. You usually do one or the other, but not both.